# can i place all my .bash* file in to a directory?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bashrc

i have quite a few .bash* file in `~/`

- .bash_aliases
- .bash_history
- .bash_logout
- .bashrc

Can i put all these files in to a `~/.bash` directory and if so how, or would it just break?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Any/every Linux system — and Unix-like systems like macOS — have these files in a user’s home directory. The system expects to find them exactly where you are seeing them. You move them and you effectively delete them as far as the system goes. So no, you cannot just decide to put them in a directory like `~/.bash` without screwing up your terminal login process.  Additionally, even if you did do this, the `.bash_history` would be recreated because that is effectively a log of terminal activity and not a random config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can but it would be of little to no benefit for MOST people.  You would still need to create links to these files back into your home directory ($HOME/~).

One reason might be like I do for WSL. I keep them in a directory where they can be easily edited from my native operating system and I link them back to the home directory. WSL1 will break if I mess with files under the root directory but not my windows mounts.

Comment: Again.. why the downvote?  You could at least be a grown up and tell me.  There is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."